# Why does Twitter use so many <div>s for its fixed position navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build up a website with a Navigation bar on top of the page. It should be fixed on top of the browser when we scroll the page (like facebook or twitter), but not scroll with the page(like google search??). see Fig like:[image]
seems like we should set the css attribute **position** of this navigation bar  like

```
#nav_bar {
  postion:fixed;
}
```

but why all those websites use a whole bunch of div to do this? Does all these divs make any sence? Like twitter:[image]
where topbar *js-topbar* is the outmost *div* which size is 1583*40px, but I didnt find the definition of its size. And then it goes to global-nav->global-nav-inner->container, finally...container, which is acutually hold the navgation items like a list, a search bar so on and so forth. something Weired is  that the size of it is 865*0px. For more information, you can view source of the home page of twitter.
And my question is : but why all those websites use a whole bunch of div to do this? Does all these divs make any sence? Why is a div which height is 0px can hold those navigation items?

Comment: use position:absolute; if you don't want it move with you when scrolling. position:fixed; if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### why the 'many' divs?

The general idea is the more wrapping elements you have the more flexibility you have with regards to what you can achieve in styling with css. Obviously there is a limit, as you should also try to keep your markup readable and semantic. I would say many important or segregated regions in a site would benefit from three wrapping elements:

```
<div class="positioner">
  <div class="padder">
    <div class="alignment">
      Menu Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously with the more semantic HTML5 elements you can make this more readable:

```
<header class="positioner">
  <div class="padding>
    <nav class="alignment">
      Menu Here
    </nav> 
  </div>
</header>
```

- The reason for keeping a seperate element for padding is so that you can set specific dimensions to your positioner *(i.e. header)* and not have that calculation messed up on certain browsers *(with old box modles)* by the addition of padding.
- The reason for keeping alignment seperate is because it will give you greater flexibility on the alignment tricks you can use.
- The reason for using the header element is because this content will act as a header imo.

The example you give above, each element will most definitely have it's reason for existing and they will most probably all be used to achieve the layout the designer wanted with regard to css. Some times extra wrapping divs are also used as placeholders for content that may be AJAXed, this is probably quite likely when dealing with the likes of Twitter.

You can of course get away with using only a single wrapping element, but you will be limiting what styling and positioning you can achieve later on down the line.

#### why the height 0px?

There is a trick often used with positioning absolute layers in a relative location *(rather than an absolute location)* - and I believe this is the reason why you are seeing this, but the trick in itself isn't the actual cause of the `height:0px`. The trick uses the following construction:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute;">
    The content here will float outside of the document flow, 
    but remain in the correct location within the document flow
     - in all viable browsers.
  </div>
</div>
```

If you inspect the above construction, using any browser debug method, you will notice that the `position: absolute;` layer has collapsed to have no height *(in modern browsers)*. This is the default behaviour of position absolute outside of the old Internet Explorer world *(with no other positioning or dimensions settings)*, because an absolutely position element is taken out of the document flow and by default doesn't calculate anything to do with it's children.

If you wish to override this behaviour you can simply use `overflow:hidden;` *(as long as the height has NOT been specifically set to 0px by some other class or by JavaScript)* - this will force the element to calculate the dimensions of it's children and wrap them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use position:absolute; if you don't want it move with you when scrolling. position:fixed; if you do.

Second of all when you build a website the first thing you're going to have to do is decide how the structure of your website is going to look like. So the menu at the top will be

```
<div id="Menu"> </div>
```

Now you may want to create a header under it

```
<div id="Header"> </div>
```

Under that you want to share content, since thats what website do.

```
<div id="Content"> </div>
```

Under that you may want a footer, that says 2012 Copyright etc.

```
<div id="Footer">2012 Copyright zoujyjs &copy; </div>
```

Now you may want to center everything. Why not just put all these previous divs inside a wrapper div. Then all we have to do is center the wrapper div.

```
<div id="Wrapper">
      <div id="Menu"> </div>
      <div id="Header"> </div>
      <div id="Content"> </div>
      <div id="Footer"> </div>
</div>
```

You could also add stuff like a logo inside the header, etc.

I think you get the idea. But isn't it obvious you're going to get "divception" then?

Also: When no height is specified on a div, the div will automatically resize with the content within.

```
<div style="background-color:black;">
   <!-- Nothing will be seen on your page, because the div is 0 height, 0 width by                default -->
</div>


<div style="background-color:black;">
   Height of the div will now be the same height as the height of this line. (15 px by    default I believe
</div>
```

Comment: you're welcome mate. As long as you learn from it. Basically my comment is saying div's are used to structure ur page so you can style them in CSS. Now when you want something inside a header, like a logo all you have to do is add an image, put it inside #Header and style it to margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px; or whatever you like ;)